# maven release/deploy to github packages

Tags: git, maven, github, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to release my javadocs to gh-pages and the maven repo to the github maven repo. The site seems to deploy alright, but the release plugin is failing. It seems to be failing to find the github credentials which I have configured. Is this a bug in one of maven plugins, or did I somehow fail to specify the proper credentials?

pom.xml:

```
<scm>
    <url>https://github.com/${repo.user}/${repo.name}</url>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/${repo.user}/${repo.name}.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/${repo.user}/${repo.name}.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub</name>
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/${repo.user}/${repo.name}</url>
    </repository>
    <site>
        <id>gh-pages</id>
        <name>Github</name>
        <url>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/${repo.user}/${repo.name}.git</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

settings.xml:

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>${env.GITHUB_API_USERNAME}</username>
            <password>${env.GITHUB_API_KEY}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>gh-pages</id>
            <username>git</username>
            <configuration>
                <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
                <scmVersion>gh-pages</scmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_ecdsa
```

output, mvn release:prepare:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project ia: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
[ERROR] Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.4' to the list of known hosts.
[ERROR] <my username>:********@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Edit:
Changing settings.xml to use 'git' username causes this error instead:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.<user>:<repo>:<version>-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/<User>/<Repo>): Authentication failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/<User>/<Repo>/com/<user>/<repo>/<version>-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 401 Unauthorized
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy (default-deploy)
```

Edit:
If it helps, the corporate parent POM (where I'm currently working) is here:
https://github.com/InnovAnon-Inc/IA

and a "simple" child project is here:
https://github.com/InnovAnon-Inc/SimpleJavaPrograms

The parent POM should be a fairly simple and generic one... hopefully nothing too weird is going on in there.

The child project is weird: one developer is a beginner, using a toy IDE. I want the project and tests to be able to be run from within that IDE, so it uses a "simple" directory structure, instead of the standard one. Furthermore, I want to be able to run this project through a dev ops pipeline that runs the unit tests, creates easy-to-use artifacts, and deploys the docs and artifacts. This way, the beginner doesn't have to learn any extra-curricular topics, such as build systems, in order to benefit from a test-driven development strategy. Collaboration will also be simpler, since I will be able to view the test results, stack traces and the current source code.

Edit:
I'll be happy with any solution that will deploy these FOSS artifacts to a free repo, so they are usable with Maven.

Ultimately, I'd like to deploy three things:

1. the site/javadocs to gh-pages
2. the normal maven artifacts to a maven repo
3. the (possibly executable) jar-with-dependencies to the github release/downloads

The second deployment objective handles the normal, enterprise-grade use case: the client code builds with maven and simply declares the dependency.

The third deployment objective handles the simple, beginner-level use case: the user manually downloads the jar-with-dependencies.

For applications, these are packaged as executable jars with the proper manifest so that `java -jar <artifact>.jar` works.

For libraries, these are simply jar-with-dependencies, so beginners don't have to learn about manually managing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you see `<my username>:********@github.com` instead of `git:********@github.com`, your SSH key will fail to authenticate you on GitHub.

A GitHub SSH URL would *always* use the remote user "`git`", never "`<my username>`".
Check if the release manven plugin is using the username server setting, which would explain why you see your username.

Comment: I changed settings.xml to use <username>git</username> and now I get a 401 unauthorized error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1:deploy (default-deploy)... 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]

Comment: @user1456735 Is it also at the push stage like in your original question? I don't think the username should be changed to git.

Comment: @user1456735 I just seen your edit: the username must remain unchanged. But the developerConnection should be used when pushing.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be using the developerConnection. It is using the distributionManagement repository (https://maven.pkg.github.com). I think the ssh/git connections are working (for, e.g., site:deploy). It's just the release plugin that is using this https connection and failing.